# How to select first rows when column changes value in numpy.array

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a nice quick way to do the following selection for numpy arrays?

```
>>> A=np.array([[1,2], [2,2], [3,5], [4,5]])
>>> A
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 5],
       [4, 5]])
```

I would like to select the first rows when the second column changes value. For the above array, the result would be:

```
array([[1, 2], 
       [3, 5]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> xs = np.array([[1,2], [2,2], [3,5], [4,5]])
>>> j = scipy.r_[True, xs[:-1,1] != xs[1:,1]]  # or np.concatenate here
>>> xs[j,:]
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 5]])
```